# Android library project - export

Tags: android, apk

I have an android project which includes a library project.
In this library project, I included many drawables and animations.

The problem is that when I export the main project as an .apk, it includes all drawables and animations, even the one which are not used in the main project.

How could I exlude the useless drawables when exporting ?

UPDATE : 
I can not delete the drawables, they are used in other projects. 
This library is used by many projects.

Comment: This is supposed to be automatically handled by earlier version of ADT, but seems to be changed since r14 as Android team start redesign and introduce jar file exporting for library project. so just my guess as I cannot find articles talking about library resource filtering/refinement any more.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete them before exporting